# Why am I recieving the error message "Runtime Error '91'" abd How can I fix this?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA and Macros, this is my first attempt to code. So... I have a word document that functions as a template for report generation. The word document has tables/charts linked to an excel document. I am trying to create a macro that will take the existing source linked in the word document and change/Update them to the new desired location. The idea is to have the user run the macro and then be prompted to choose an excel file and the macro will automatically update all of the tables and charts.

I am receiving a

> " Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

message for the following line:

```
ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = newFile
```

After doing some research, I believe the problem is that I am assigning an object variable to a value. Which instead needs to be "set" due to it being an object? Therefore, I have tried changing the line to the following

```
Set ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = newFile
```

which in return gets a

> "Compile error: Invalid use of property"

message on the `.SourceFullName` part of the code.

As previously mentioned, I am a complete newbie and am effectively lost at this point. Any advice and pointers will be welcomed. I have palns in the future to automate other aspects of the report but this is the main time-consumer of the report process and is the reason as to why I am starting with this.

Thanks Guys!

```
Sub changeSource()

Dim dlgSelectFile As FileDialog 'FileDialog object '
Dim thisField As Field
Dim selectedFile As Variant

Dim newFile As Variant
Dim fieldCount As Integer '
Dim x As Integer

Set dlgSelectFile = Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)


With dlgSelectFile
   .Filters.Clear 'clear filters
  .Filters.Add "Microsoft Excel Files", "*.xls, *.xlsb, *.xlsm, *.xlsx" 'filter for only Excel files
  'use Show method to display File Picker dialog box and return user's action

  If .Show = -1 Then
    For Each selectedFile In .SelectedItems
         newFile = selectedFile 'gets new filepath
       Next selectedFile
     Else 'user clicked cancel
   Exit Sub
  End If
End With
Set dlgSelectFile = Nothing

'update fields
  fieldCount = ActiveDocument.Fields.Count
  For x = 1 To fieldCount
    ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = newFile
  Next x

MsgBox "Source data has been successfully imported."


End Sub
```

Comment: When you step through your code, what is the value of fieldcount and newFile?

Comment: It's not clear what the `For` loop is supposed to be doing with `newFile`, nor what kind of data `newFile` should contain. Especially since it's declared as a `Variant`. It's almost as if you want to store multiple file paths, yet this won't happen - it will store only the last path... But I have to wonder what it is being stored *as*. So try `Dim newFile As String` instead of `Variant`. `SourceFullName` needs a `String`; it's possible that what's being stored in the `Variant` is causing problems. Note: `Set` is definitely not needed here as `SourceFullName` is a *property*, not an `Object`.